# Is it possible to return an error for an extra query parameter shows up in light-4j request

Tags: light-4j

I have a question about the light-rest-4j URL validation, for example, if I have a POST request path /party, if I type the path as /party11, I will get error: No handler defined for path /party11, but if I put /party?qqqq, It will pass through, and system treat it as /party should we add validation for this? Our QA team creates this as a defect, in case user input it by mistake, they expect to have error message return.

Answer (score 0):

The light-rest-4j framework validates the request/response based on the OpenAPI specification during the runtime; however, it only validates based on the spec — nothing more and nothing less. In most cases, the spec will define the type of headers, query parameters, path parameters, and cookies, as well as if they are required. We make sure these are validated as defined. For anything that is not defined in the spec, we are doing nothing. For example, an extra query parameter or an extra header in the request will be ignored as they are not defined in the spec. We cannot do any negative validation as we don't know if any client will add additional headers or query parameters for tracing, auditing, etc. A request that comes from one client might be different than another one comes from the same client through a gateway or proxy.